# Randomly Mixing An Array, But In A Calculated Way

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I am trying to figure out a way to "randomly" mix a large array with more than 500,000 integers. I can currently randomly mix the array with:

```
let offset = Int(randomNumber(uni: pixelCount-1))
array.append(offset)
let pixel = rgba.pixels[index]
let newIndex = rgba.pixels.index(index, offsetBy: (offset-index), limitedBy: pixelCount)
```

But this is not really what I'm looking for since the mixed array will be different each time I create it. What I am looking for is a way to mix the array, but in a calculated manner that can be repeated so I can reverse the array back to its original state.  Can anyone help?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Set a seed for the RNG at the start.  The same seed should give the same sequence of random numbers.  A different seed will give a different sequence.

Comment: @rossum I use the pixelCount-1 as the "seed" but the numbers generated are different each time.  Is there a different method that I need to use other than randomNumber(uni: _ )?

Comment: Try setting an explicit number, `42` say.  See if that works.